# How to keep user ckecked rows checked even after end of search in jqGrid?

Tags: jqgrid

Whenever we select rows the in jqGrid and perform search operation at the end search reloads the grid and all the user checked rows are unchecked .... I want the selected rows to be selected even after search perform or we go to next page.

Does anyone have solution on this?????? I need it URGENT

Answer (score 0):

You should remember the selected rows before search and select them again after. For example, you define onSearch event:

```
var selected_rows = [];

onSearch: function(){
    selected_rows = $('#your_grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
}
```

Then you define gridComplete event, so that it would select the rows if any:

```
gridComplete: function(){
    $.each(selected_rows, function(_, row_id){
        $("#your_grid").jqGrid('setSelection', row_id, false);
    });
    selected_rows = [];
}
```

You can use onPaging event in similar way to deal with paging.